# Nest list date filter

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

In my index I have documents of type attraction they have a property which is a list of offers.  Those offers have an expiry date. Each attraction can have more then one offer (the offers property is a list of offers).

What I am trying to do is filter out all attactions that have all expired offers attached to them.

I have got this far:

```
private QueryContainer AddExpiredOffersFilter(QueryContainerDescriptor<AttractionDocument> query)
{
    query.DateRange(d => d.Field(f => f.Offers.First().Expires).GreaterThan(DateTime.Now));
    return query;
}
```

However that is only for the first attached offer.  How would i go about filtering over all the attached offers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Max on the array and compare it to the Datetime.now.

Important tips: Please note that .First() doesnot means only to the first item (moreoever elastic doesnot keep the item order in the indexaction). The whole array is analysed (but indeed, .Field operator is a Or, so doesnot work with your case, could work with a must_not bool parent clause btw).

```
   private QueryContainer AddExpiredOffersFilter(QueryContainerDescriptor<AttractionDocument> query)
    {
        query.DateRange(d => d.Field(f => f.Offers.Max(r => r.Expires)).GreaterThan(DateTime.Now));
        return query;
    }
```

Comment: figured out after posting that First() does not mean first item. many thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

ok so after some experimentation I have something working, forgot to mention I also need to ignore if expiry date not set

```
        private QueryContainer AddExpiredOffersFilter(QueryContainerDescriptor<AttractionDocument> query)
    {

        return (
            (
                +query.Exists(d => d.Field(f => f.Offers.First().Expires))
                &&
                +query.DateRange(d => d
                    .Field(f => f.Offers.First().Expires)
                    .GreaterThanOrEquals(DateTime.Now)
                )
            )
            ||
            (
                !query.Exists(d => d
                    .Field(f => f.Offers.First().Expires)
                )
            )
        );

    }
```